# Defining javascript function while referencing local variable

Tags: javascript, function

Is it possible to use the current value of a variable when defining a javascript function?
In the following code I'd like to add a click function to an array of divs, each with a different value for `i`, ie. the first div should call `setCurrentStyleIndex(0)`. At the moment they all call whatever the value of `i` is at the time of the call.

Sorry if this is dumb question.

```
Step3.populateStyleMenu = function() {
    var stylePopup = $("#stylePopup");
    for(var i = 0; i < Step3.fontStyles.length; i++) {
        var div = $('<div>'+Step3.fontStyles[i][0]+'</div>');
        div.css({
            'font-weight': Step3.fontStyles[i][1],
            'font-style': Step3.fontStyles[i][2],
        })
        div.data('style', Step3.fontStyles[i]);
        div.addClass('personalizePopupItem personalizeStyleItem');


        div.click(function() {
            setCurrentStyleIndex(i);
        });


        stylePopup.append(div);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to create a closure (not tested):

```
(function (i) {
    div.click(function() {
        setCurrentStyleIndex(i);
    });
})(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you can do the below:

```
div.click((function() {
  var inx = i;
  return function() {
    setCurrentStyleIndex(inx);
  }
})());
```